# Subfigure arrangement - first image is raised

Tags: floats, subcaption, layout, subfig

I am using LaTeX to write my thesis and have found a problem when I try to insert subfigures. I am using the package subcaption.

This is the code I have used

```
\begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/K=11OC.png}
         \label{fig:K=11OC}
         \caption{}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/K=11.png}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:K=11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/K=11T.png}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:K=11T}
    \end{subfigure}
\label{fig:Kthr}
\end{figure}
```

and this is the output I receive :

[image]

All of the pictures are the same size and layout.
The same thing happens with any subfigures I try to insert, regardless of the number of subfigures, the 1st one is always raised in comparison to the rest.
I suspect maybe there is conflict between packages, but as I am new to LaTeX, I used a thesis template, so I am not too sure what all of the packages do. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly you are exceeding the `\textwidth`. Try with `0.31` or even `0.3\textwidth` or in other case use `%` symbol after each end of the commands :  `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/K=11OC.png}%`
         `\label{fig:K=11OC}%`
         `\caption{}%`
     `\end{subfigure}%`
     `\hfill%`

This will eliminate the spaces that been currently added between the images ... (maybe only after `\end{subfigure}` and `\hfill` is the places that this will take effect.. because `subfigure` environment is possibly ignoring the spaces in it)

Comment: You show no use of any packages (apart from mentioning `subcaption`) so how can anyone guess if there is any conflict between them? (I could say that there might be a conflict between the 2nd and 6th of your packages, but I won't --- GOM)

Comment: Switch `\caption` and `\label` in your first `subfigure` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `\label` after the `\caption` command in all three `subfigure` environments in order to get the correct alignment and cross references.

In the following MWE, the only difference between the two `figure` environments in the order of `\caption` and `\label`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/K=11OC.png}
         \label{fig:K=11OC} % <------- should be placed after the caption
         \caption{}  
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/K=11.png}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:K=11}
    \end{subfigure}
\label{fig:Kthr}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/K=11OC.png}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:K=11OC}  
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/K=11.png}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:K=11}
    \end{subfigure}
\label{fig:Kthr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```